# Symfony Swiftmailer: Conditionally spool emails or send immediately

Tags: symfony, email, conditional-statements, swiftmailer, spool

Has anyone ever set a condition on spooling emails with Swiftmailer in Symfony?
I'd like to have the option to either send my emails immediately or spool them in a file, depending on which function I'm running.

I have the email service abstracted in an own Bundle and just call the sendEmail() function in other Bundles when needed. But for some Bundles/Functions, I'd like the emails to be sent out immediately and for others, spooling is fine. I thought about using a **spool** parameter in my sendEmail() function, so if the parameter is set true when calling the function, the emails get spooled and if it's set to false, they get send immediately.

Or maybe a simple if condition would be sufficient?]

Any ideas, tips, experiences etc. would be awesome!

**Update**

in my config.yml:

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:
          type: file
          path: /srv/http/test/spool
```

Comment: Swiftmailer supports [spooling by default](https://symfony.com/doc/current/email/spool.html), you simply need to set a cron job to run periodically to clear the spool

Comment: but what if i don't want my emails to be spooled? I only want them to get spooled in certain situations. that's what I intended to say with my Question

Comment: This is possible, can you show how the `Swift_Mailer` instance is being loaded/configured?

Comment: Yes, I added it to my question @WilliamPerron :)

Answer (score 1):

By specifying a `spool` option in the parameters, Swiftmailers will use an instance of [`Swift_Transport_SpoolTransport`](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/master/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/SpoolTransport.php) which will manage the spool by sending messages to the Queue instead of instead of sending them out to the world straight away. Through the `Transport` object, you can access the `Spool` instance (either a [`Swift_MemorySpool`](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/master/lib/classes/Swift/MemorySpool.php) or a [`Swift_FileSpool`](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/master/lib/classes/Swift/FileSpool.php)) and force Swiftmailer to flush the queue.

```
// custom function to send an email
// inject \Swift_Mailer like you normally would
public function sendMessage($name, \Swift_Mailer $mailer, $bypassSpool = false)
{
    $message = new \Swift_Message('Hello Email')
        ->setFrom(/* from */)
        ->setTo(/* to */)
        ->setBody(/* render view */);

    $mailer->send($message); // pushes the message to the spool queue

    if($bypassSpool) {
        $spool = $mailer->getTransport->getSpool()
        $spool->flushQueue(new Swift_SmtpTransport(
            /* Get host, username and password from config */
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: before I mark your answer one quick question:
is it really necessary to add the parameters to the new Transport instance? I tried it without the parameters and it worked out, but I was wondering what the difference to adding the parameters would be?

Comment: oh and one more question: is there a way to only flush the messages that were created at that time? because when I now flush the Queue, obviously, all the messages in my spool file get sent out.

Comment: @sonja to your first question: Maybe. I haven't tried it and stuck with what the official documentation for the answer, but it wouldn't surprised me if it defaulted to the config params. To your second question, sure, but you'd need to create a new instance of `Swift_FileSpool` each time, since the only to change the save path is through the constructor, and then create a new instance of `Swift_Mailer` because you can't change it's `Transport` once it is initialized

Comment: @sonja, imo the complexity that would result of this wouldn't be worth it. I would simply use `MemorySpool` which flushes its queue when the kernel terminates, i.e. when the request is over, so it doesn't bottleneck the request

Comment: thanks a lot! I thought about adding a second spool file for that occasion but couldn't find anyone else who already did that. Do you have an idea whether or how that would work?

Comment: @sonja I have no done that, so unfortunately no. If you want, we can continue this conversation over in the chat. I am currently at work but should be able to check it intermittently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158081/discussion-between-william-perron-and-sonja).

Answer (score 0):

You can [configure two mailers](https://symfony.com/doc/2.5/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html#using-multiple-mailers). One with spooling and another without. And use one or the other based on mail priority.